# Configure facebook login button for Business not allowed to add config_id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, single-sign-on, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a Facebook Business web app in a react project and want to add `config_id` while logging in. As the documentation mentioned for the business web app, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/facebook-login-for-business, we can add `config_id` in `FB.login()` and on a click of HTML button, we can do the login.

But I don't want use the HTML button and want to use Facebook Login Button which is documented here. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button, I am using following thing to add the Facebook button,

```
<div 
  className="fb-login-button"
  data-max-rows="1"
  data-size="large"
  data-button-type="login_with"
  data-layout=""
  data-use-continue-as="true"
></div>
```

But I could not find a way to add `config_id` here and I am kind of stuck here for using Facebook login button for Facebook business app. Is there a way to add the `config_id` here?

Answer (score 0):

You can add config_id just like the other properties using data. Like below;

```
   <div
            className="fb-login-button"
            data-width=""
            data-size="medium"
            data-button-type="continue_with"
            data-layout="default"
            data-auto-logout-link="false"
            data-use-continue-as="true"
            data-onlogin={() => facebookLogin}
            data-config_id={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_CONFIG_ID}
          ></div>
```